# Query is pulling the same post twice

Tags: php, wordpress

After seeking help and failing, I managed to write a query for Wordpress that does exactly what it's suppose to do, however it pulls the post that it's suppose to in twice. I've stared and stared at the markup and I can't see why it's doing it. Here's the query:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'supplier-tax',
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'supplier-tax');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $termID[] = $term->term_id;
    } 

    $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'supplier',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => '$termID',
        ),
    ) ); ?>

    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p class="supplier">Supplied by <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>
        <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>">
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

If anybody could help, or point out where I'm going wrong so that i can learn from it, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by `however it pulls the post that it's suppose to in twice.`?

Comment: At the moment theres only one post connected with term of the taxonomy it's getting, and when it pulls that post into the page, it does it twice, it gives the content twice. Essentially putting two of the same post on a page

Comment: it is because the loop run twice. what am i understand is : that you want post from custom post type `supplier` where `supplier-tax` taxonomy linked with ? is it ?

Comment: Yes essentially, I have two custom post types and a post in each post type will share a `term` in the `supplier-tax` taxonomy. I need to pull the post that shares the same term into the other post's page.

Comment: you want post attached with category `supplier-tax` please confirm ?

Comment: Yes but not just posts attached to the `supplier-tax' taxonomy, Needs to be post attached to the same term inside `supplier-tax`. Basically The query above without it looping twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

Just in case anybody ever has any trouble querying a post with the same `term` of a `Taxonomy` in another `Post Type`. I'll post my answer below because I finally solved it on my own.

```
<?php 

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'supplier-tax');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $termID[] = $term->term_id;
}

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'supplier',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'supplier-tax',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => '$termID',
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

   <p class="supplier">Supplied by <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>
   <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>">

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I hope this helps someone because this was hard to find a solution too.

Comment: in variable $termID,you get taxonomy id and you pass that $termiD in query array filter by "SLUG"..! you can use 'field' =>'term_id'...

Answer (score 0):

It will return all the post associated with taxonomy & post type your provide .

1st answer :

```
    $term_slug = get_query_var('term'); 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('product','supplier'),
        'tax_query' => array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'supplier-tax',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $term_slug,
                    )
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <p class="supplier">Supplied by <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>
            <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>">
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

?>

2nd answer :

```
$posts = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'supplier-tax' ); echo '<pre>';print_r($posts);echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but, it pulls all the posts in from that taxonomy, I only need to pull the posts from the corresponding term

Comment: what is the  corresponding term name ?

Comment: It changes on every page which is what the following code did `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'supplier-tax');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $termID[] = $term->term_id;
    } ` it got the term name, for you to create a variable and use that.

Comment: hey try this , is it working fine `$posts = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'supplier-tax' );  echo '<pre>';print_r($post);echo '</pre>'; ` just remove all code and try.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show me where it's suppose to go

Comment: No produces the same result as it did before

Comment: i have changed the answer added `term_slug`. it still not working with adjacent post also with my updated answer ?

Comment: Where do I put `$posts = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'supplier-tax' ); echo '<pre>';print_r($post);echo '</pre>';` can you edit that in to your answer?

Comment: try 2nd answer and remove 1st answer from your php file.

Comment: Just displays all the information about the currrent post

Comment: oh sorry it was `$posts` not `$post` updated `echo '<pre>';print_r($posts);echo '</pre>';`

Comment: That just gives the `WP Post Object` information for the other post in that term with the same post type